# Show top of activity , if when app is opened, if a notification comes

Tags: android, push-notification

I want to show notification on top of activity if app is already opened. And no notification sound : ) 
Hi, If the app is not opened, I want it to come up on normal notification and make a sound. If the application is opened, I want popup notification and no sound..Please help me. 
This is my code.

```
        NotificationCompat.Builder b = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext());

    b.setAutoCancel(true)
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.welcome)
            .setTicker("" + getResources().getString(R.string.notif))
            .setContentTitle(message + " : " + hican)
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS | Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
            .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
            .setContentInfo("ABC")
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                    .bigText(icerik));
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(1, b.build());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want notification sound, just remove `Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND` in your line `.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS | Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)`

Write it as `.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS)`

And if you mean to show a popup notification (`Heads-up Notifications`), try and set notification priority to `Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH` or `Notification.PRIORITY_MAX`.

add this line `.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH)`

Comment: Hi, If the app is not opened, I want it to come up on normal notification and make a sound. If the application is opened, I want popup notification and no sound..

Comment: You know Whatsapp app. Like it.

Comment: The WhatsApp does not have a **Welcome notification*** !!! What exactly are you asking for???